# How to properly pull my data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, json, database, firebase

VERY new to Firebase, but using it for big project.

I just finished my log in activity and I am trying to pull a (String) username and (Long) score from my Firebase. I need to update the data and to have it NOT be null.

Please, I need help with the logic/application of the `MainActivity.class`, which is passed an (String) email and (String) authID, and the Firebase API. I I have done the research but I have gotten to a point where I dunno what I did wrong. It truly all looks fine to me. Please help!

Thank you in advance!!

My Firebase data is as follows (I think):

```
{
HOME:{
user_accts:{
          $uid:{
              score:{(Long) num}
              userName:{(String) email}
          }
}
}//end of JSON unit
```

Below is my `UserAccount` class:

```
package com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt;

public class UserAccount {

    // private String firstName = null;
    // private String lastName = null;
    private String userName = null;
    private long score = 0;

    public UserAccount() {}

    public UserAccount(String userName, Long score) {
        // this.firstName = firstName;
        // this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public long getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}//end of class
```

Below is the class in its entirety:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static final String FIREBASE_TO_HOME = "https:..";

    public static final String FIREBASE_TO_HOME_TO_USERACCTS = "https:...";

    private static final String FIREBASE_USER_AUTHID = "FIREBASE-AUTH-UID";

    private static final String FIREBASE_USER_EMAIL = "FIREBASE-AUTH-EMAIL";

    private static final String USER_PREF_AUTH = "USER-AUTH";

    private static final String USER_PREF_SCORE = "USER-SCORE";

    Firebase homeRef;
    Firebase userRef;

    private String userAuthUid;
    private String userEmail;
    private Long userScore;

    SharedPreferences bountyHuntPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_nav_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        homeRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_TO_HOME);
        bountyHuntPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefEditor = bountyHuntPrefs.edit();

        TextView emailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        TextView scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);
        Button resetPass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_resetPass);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // add user to homeDB
        // update the users account
        // User passed auth, get them in
        userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra(FIREBASE_USER_EMAIL);
        userAuthUid = getIntent().getStringExtra(FIREBASE_USER_AUTHID);
        if (userAuthUid!=null) {
            prefEditor.putString(USER_PREF_AUTH, userAuthUid).apply();
            userAuthUid = null;
        }

        getUserDataFromMemory();
        // TODO: Set user info into UI elements
        emailTextView.setText(userEmail);
    scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(userScore));//Long.toString(userScore)
        resetPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Reset Password?")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to reset your password?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Reset", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            homeRef.resetPassword(userEmail, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error, could not reset", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // dismiss
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        ...
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        ...
    }

    private void getUserDataFromMemory() {

        userScore = bountyHuntPrefs.getLong(USER_PREF_SCORE, 0);

        userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_TO_HOME_TO_USERACCTS).child(bountyHuntPrefs.getString(USER_PREF_AUTH, ""));
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot userSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserAccount user = userSnapShot.getValue(UserAccount.class);
                    userEmail = user.getUserName();
                    if (userScore == 0)
                        userScore = user.getScore();
                    prefEditor.putLong(USER_PREF_SCORE, userScore).apply();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Authentication", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                homeRef.unauth();
                homeRef = null;
                finish();
            }
        });
        UserAccount user = new UserAccount(userEmail, userScore);
        userRef.setValue(user);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Log user out and kill activity
        super.onStop();
        homeRef.unauth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        userAuthUid = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(USER_PREF_AUTH, userAuthUid);
    }
}//end of class
```

**LOGCAT ERROR:**

```
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt, PID: 4796
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:219)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:158)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt.UserAccount] from Integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromInt(StdValueInstantiator.java:320)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromNumber(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1012)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:138)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:123)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt.MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:219) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:158) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
11-16 20:59:43.445 4796-4796/com.frankbrenyahapps.maphunt E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: What happens? Error message (pls add to question), unexpected behavior (pls also describe expected behavior then) or something else?

Comment: I don't see in your code where you make an API call to Firebase. Have you looked at their tutorials?

Comment: @cricket_007 check `getUserDataFromMemory()` it registers a listener for data change

Comment: @zapi The error message is along the lines of "Failed to bound" and is caused by the first line inside my value change listener, here:`UserAccount user = userSnapShot.getValue(UserAccount.class);`.I tried using the for-loop as suggested in the tutorials for retrieving data but it STILL crashes there. I will add it to the question. Thanks

Comment: Ah - I guess I wasn't registering "from Memory" with a database

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry if it was confusing. That method was initially meant to pull data from Firebase and save it to SharedPreferences in order for me to close the listener and use the data pulled that way...but that changed when I wasnt pulling the proper data and now it crashes right away.

Comment: Your error looks like it is trying to find a constructor in UserAccount with a single Integer parameter. `no single-int-arg constructor/factory method`

Comment: @criket_007 Hmm, I see. Could you help me understand why it would do that? I have the empty constructor and the one with params like required. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be reading a single user, but are then trying to loop over the children. This means that your `userSnapShot.getValue(UserAccount.class)` will be invoked on the `userName` and `score` properties, which themselves are not `UserAccount` objects.

The solution is to remove the loop:

```
userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_TO_HOME_TO_USERACCTS).child(bountyHuntPrefs.getString(USER_PREF_AUTH, ""));
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserAccount user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserAccount.class);
        userEmail = user.getUserName();
        if (userScore == 0)
            userScore = user.getScore();
        prefEditor.putLong(USER_PREF_SCORE, userScore).apply();
    }
```

### Update - answers to questions from the comments

The `onCancelled()` method is typically invoked when you don't have read rights to the data.

Updating the user's score can be as simple as `userRef .child("score").setValue(42)`. Or by saving the entire user: `user.setScore(42); userRef.setValue(user);` (you'll need to create a `setScore()` method for this).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried that before. It stops from crashing but then the handler `onCancelled(Error)` is invoked. What does that mean? Also, what logic can I follow in order to grab the score (or username), work with it, then update the firebase data. I feel its a stupid question, but I am beat from working on this all day.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, my rules deny access to auth == null and when I start another activity and relaunch this one (go back), my auth is null. Can you see why?

Comment: More answers above. But we're stretching the understanding of a question quite a bit by now. Please provide a [**minimal**, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a single problem in your next question.